# what is meant by this statement c=calendarTextCalendar()

Tags: python

what is meant by this statement c=calendar.TextCalendar() ,in this calendar and textcalendar() are functions or classes?

Answer (score -1):

It generates a text calendar. Read the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html

`calendar` here is the name of the package and `TextCalendar`is the name of the class